# Transmitting input through USB from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, usb, input, mouse

I am making a device, similar to a cross between a controller and a mouse, and I wondered how I would send input to the computer.
For example:
Transmitting movement, buttons pressed etc.
Also, how would I make it so the computer automatically detects it as a mouse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you starting from scratch, or using a framework / HAL / OS that exists? (e.g: Arduino, Zephyr, etc...) You're probably most interested in the ["Human Interface Device" class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class).

Comment: The normal way to do this would be with a library for your microcontroller that implements USB HID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up how USB works.

When plugged in, there is an enumeration process where PC asks what kind of device was connected, and in this case, your device likely wants to tell the PC that it a mouse or some other standard HID device. Then you need to send movement and button changes in USB packects according to HID standard.